# Sublime Text 3 custom build nothing happens

Tags: python-3.x, build, sublimetext3

I'm new to fiddling with Sublime Text 3 settings and such. I'm learning to make my own build system, and for now I just want to make a simple Python 3 build system, which is not included by default. (Why is Python 2 still the default by the way!?) Anyway, I've read some [documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_processing/build_systems.html) and followed the instructions. I've created the `.sublime-build` file below.

```
{
    "shell_cmd": ["python3", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

I've stored this file as `python3.sublime-build` under `/Users/ray/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User`. Sublime Text 3 is able to detect this file, and I'm able to select it to build. However, when I build with it, **nothing happens**. When I build with the default `Python` build system, everything is fine and it runs and shows me the build results in a little subwindow at the bottom, but when I use my `python3.sublime-build` build system, nothing happens at all. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `shell_cmd` instead of `cmd`. The former does not seem to support the list format for the command, where as the latter does. Either change the command to be a single string `"python3 -u \"$file\""` or use `cmd`.

From the [documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems/exec.html) for the `exec` command:

`cmd`:

> Array containing the command to run and its desired arguments.

`shell_cmd`:

> A string that specifies the command to be run and its arguments.

Comment: Ah yes of course. I didn't even notice I had `shell_cmd` because I copy-pasted it from the docs and assumed it must be correct. It makes sense given that Sublime runs Python scripts and the Python `subprocess.run()` function takes an optional argument `shell=True`, which generates the behaviour you described. Thank you.